# I am 6ft and riding a firefox kompac. My speed never crosses 18kmph

Tags: derailleur, hybrid-bike, speed

What is the difference of having larger no of teeth in the front derailleur? does it help in speed and distance covered? Suggest a good hybrid on which I can achieve faster speeds? My budget is $700.

Comment: More info would help: how many teeth on the front chain ring, how many teeth on the rear cogs? Do you have flat peddles or "clipless"?

Comment: Additionally what cadence are you riding at.

Comment: I'm SURE your speed never crosses 18kmph, given that the speed of sound is only about 0.7kmph. I presume you meant either kilometers per hour (kph) or miles per hour (mph). The latter seems more likely.

Comment: I've never gone faster than 18,000mph either.

Answer (score 3):

What is your "cadence" (number of pedal revolutions per minute)?  A healthy young cyclist should be able to "cruise" at 80-90 rpm, and that would be considered your top speed.

If at 80 rpm you're only getting 18kmph (11mph) in your fastest gear then your bike gearing is quite low and you probably need to change something.  But many novice cyclists simply pedal too slowly.

With a multi-speed bike you should focus first on getting a "reasonable" cadence (maybe 60 rpm when "taking it easy", 80-90 when trying to go fast).  "Gear down" into an easier gear until you learn to maintain cadence, then slowly increase gear difficulty to gain strength and stamina.

Comment: +1 for low cadence - the first result on google seems to indicate that this bike has a 14-28t freewheel and I'm guessing a 42t big ring, which should translate to around 30 kph, not 18 kph (but is around 18 mph).

Answer (score 2):

From the web site that bike comes with 40T chainring and a 14-28T Freewheel.
17.94 kmph is a cadence of only 50.  [bikecalc.com](http://www.bikecalc.com/speed_at_cadence)
You should be up at 80+. 
On a sprint you should go over 100.
A folding bike is not as efficient as most full size bike but gearing is not what is holding you back at 18 kmph.

[image]

Not going to give specific hybrids but there are many at that price point.  Some are more road like (smaller diameter tires).  If you are looking for road speed go for more of a road style hybrid.

[KOMPAC](http://www.firefoxbikes.com/BikeDetails.aspx?BikeId=43)

Answer (score 0):

One common problem with people who are new to cycling is that they tend to under-inflate the tyres. Too low tyre pressure means increased rolling friction which is likely to be quite noticeable. (At higher speeds the air resistance is dominant, but not really at these speeds.)

Exactly how high pressure is a hotly debated question, but as a rule it should be near the 'maximum recommended tyre pressure' indicated on the sidewall.

By the look of it, that bike comes with some knobbly off-road style tyres, but if you intend to stay on paved roads you could replace them with smoother (and narrower) tyres which would also improve the top speed.

Comment: Good point. I should check my car's tire pressure too, for the same reason. It does make a difference.